# if statement expected declaration error (swift code language)

Tags: swift

I do not see what my problem is. I am new to this Xcode stuff and i just want some help with the expected declaration error. this is my code

var myname = UITextInput.self

```
let age = Int()

if age {
print ("error")
} else {
print ("welcome," + String(myname))
}
```

xcode is showing and expected declaration. can some one please help me. thanks

Comment: What you want to compare with age in if condition ?

Answer (score 1):

Int is not convertible to Bool. You need to compare Int variable to other int value. See the code:

```
 let age = Int()

    if age > 0 {
        print ("error")
    } else {
        print ("welcome, \(myname)")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have declared age as Integer and you are trying to compare and integer with Boolean type which will give error since comparing is done with similar types. So, either you need to declare age as boolean or while comparison use integer values.

for boolean comparison

```
let age = Bool()

if age {
print ("error")
} else {
print ("welcome," + String(myname))
}
```

or for integer

```
let age = Int()

    if age == 0 {
    print ("error")
    } else {
    print ("welcome," + String(myname))
    }
```